# sign for "all" in where clause, PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Is there any sign for selecting all in a where clause? I have a where clause which is based on a variable thats based on the login. 
My problem is that I want with the same where select all when a certain user is logged in.

the $prefix is dynamic based on user.

```
("SELECT * FROM tabell WHERE prefix= '$prefix'");
```

Comment: First of all, make sure you know about SQL injection and how to prevent them (your query doesn't seem to be save, visit http://bobby-tables.com to learn how to prevent SQL injection). Also, why don't you simply do a `if/ else` condition? Like: IF special_user_name is the logged in user, then do the query without the `WHERE` part, otherwise do it with it.

Comment: first of, this is a part of an prepared PDO statement.. second, I have bounch of user and that would be alot of qustions then. Maybe that's the only way to go, but i´m asking for another solution.

Comment: This can't be a part of a prepared statement. We use placeholders in prepared statements, not variables. So may you haven't understand how they work. If you want to edit your question and show me the whole query, I can help you to make a real prepared statement. Also, how many users are we talking about, where you would need this special case?

Comment: $select = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user= :prefix";
        $stmt2 = $link->prepare($select);
        $stmt2->execute(array(
            'prefix'  => $prefix
        ));

Comment: thats not the question here

Comment: Okay, well done. So sorry I can't smell that you haven't posted the query in its actual state in your question. I just try to help. Also, please answer my question about `how many users are we alking for this special case?`

Comment: I didnt because the quetsion has nothing to do with the query it self.. i have about 40 different users. Thanks, for u trying to help though:)

Comment: Okay, one last question, then I can provide you a solid answer: Are these users special users, like admin or so? Or simply: Can you detect these users by an attribute in the database? Maybe a flag or something? Or are these just users like all others too?

Comment: detecting the user is no probs, its done by a session.

Comment: I have no problem to fix the issue with other methods, I just thought this would a neat solution to do it in the way the qustion is asked.

Comment: There's no way to do it in the qay the question is asked I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the loged user in a session `$_SESSION['user']`, try this:

```
$where = (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']=='certain-user') ? '':"WHERE prefix= '$prefix'";
$sql ="SELECT * FROM tabell $where";
```

Answer (score 0):

So acording to our discussion we had above in the comment section, I try to provide you some ideas on how to solve this problem.

I think one of the best things you could do is creating an array with all the users the exception should apply. Thats why I asked you if there's a way to get all these users from the DB. That would have been perfect. But since it doesn't seem so, I think you have to maintain the array manually.

Something like:

`$usersToCheck = array("Username1", "Username2", "Username3", "Username4");` and so on...

Then, when it comes to query the database, do the following:

```
if (in_array($_SESSION["username"], $usersToCheck)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
}
else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE prefix = :prefix";
}
```

I think thats one of the easiest ways to achieve what you want. If there's a possibility to maintain the users you want to put in the array from the database, you could even generate this array with PHP and you wouldn't have to do it manually.

**Solution 2:**

You said: "detecting the user is no probs, its done by a session."

I'm not that sure what you mean with that. But if there's something like a `$_SESSION["isSpecialUser"]` flag, then simply use this one for the if/else condition like:

```
if($_SESSION["isSpecialUser"] == 1) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
}
else {
    $query = "SLEECT * FROM tabl1 WHERE prefix = :prefix";
}
```

I hope it helped you. If you have any questions, feel free to ask anytime :)

Comment: Thanks for your delight answer... To clearify In the DB i have departmen, lets say 'aaa'.. And then if user belongs to 'aaa' then put that in a WHERE... Once again, thanks!

Comment: @Kalabalik Oh that makes the whole thing a lot easier! Then you can simply query your database for all the users that belong to 'aaa', put their names in an array and take my solution #1. Because then you don't have to fill the `$usersToCheck` array manually, you can fill if from a DB query. Also that allows you to add n-users to aaa without that you have to change the whole array all the time.

Comment: Yes, thats one way to go... Thanks, will consider which fits my needs the best:)